# Pyinstaller could not find NVCC after generating one file executable, Ubuntu 16.04LTS

Tags: nvidia, python3, cuda, libraries, executable

I have a python project that uses CUDA and Pycuda as part of the implementation. It runs with out error when executed as a python file. Then I generated an executable using pyinstaller but it gives me an error that it could not find nvcc.

here is the error that I am getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "site-packages/pytools/prefork.py", line 50, in call_capture_output
  File "subprocess.py", line 729, in __init__
  File "subprocess.py", line 1364, in _execute_child
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'nvcc': 'nvcc'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_3.py", line 151, in <module>
  File "test_3.py", line 134, in align_downward_optimized
  File "site-packages/pycuda/compiler.py", line 292, in __init__
  File "site-packages/pycuda/compiler.py", line 255, in compile
  File "site-packages/pycuda/compiler.py", line 78, in compile_plain
  File "site-packages/pycuda/compiler.py", line 50, in preprocess_source
  File "site-packages/pytools/prefork.py", line 227, in call_capture_output
  File "site-packages/pytools/prefork.py", line 61, in call_capture_output
pytools.prefork.ExecError: error invoking 'nvcc --preprocess -arch sm_61 -Ipycuda/cuda /tmp/tmp83435g34.cu --compiler-options -P': [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'nvcc': 'nvcc'
```

Comment: What version of CUDA do you have installed?  Also, does `nvcc -V` produce the version number?

Comment: CUDA version 8.0 and nvcc -v works properly. The error show up only when the project is converted to executable using pyinstaller.
```
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2016 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Tue_Jan_10_13:22:03_CST_2017
Cuda compilation tools, release 8.0, V8.0.61

```

Comment: Hmmm, OK.  Not too familiar with pyinstaller, but maybe see:  https://github.com/NVIDIA/apex/issues/368 where they claim that running `export CUDA_HOME=/usr/local/cuda` in a terminal window in bash seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

I have got a work around to this problem, which is to pass the path of nvcc to SourceModule(). This will help if pycuda is not able to find nvcc automatically.

```
from pycuda.compiler import SourceModule
import pycuda.driver as cuda
#CUDA C/C++ code goes inside SourceModule
mod = SourceModule("""kernel""", nvcc="path to nvcc")
....
```